# How to send enter to execute terminal command through serial port in c?

Tags: c, linux, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I am trying to send a command to a linux device(beaglebone black) using serial port (RS232). I can send the commmand string but I can not send the enter key so the command is not executed.
I have tried setting my command as :

```
char cd[]="my command \r\n"
```

the new line is actually send and I see a new line at the terminal but root@beagblebone does not appear. Basically it looks like this:

root@beagblebone: my command

and the cursor is on the new line but root@beagblebone does not appear.

Sorry I don't have the code with me right now, hope it is understandable. 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: we need to see the actual code you are using to send the array `cd`. Please update your Q. Did you try just a plain `\n` instead? That would be more normal for linux environments. Good luck.

Comment: We need more. You really shouldn't post until you have the entire problem.

Comment: Are you sure of your reason for the command not being executed?  Much depends on what the Beaglebone does with the data it receives over the serial channel.  Feeding it to a shell as input is by no means the only possibility.  Seeing it echoed to the terminal does not necessarily mean it is processed by the shell.

Comment: Maybe your command hangs? What do you try to execute? "sleep 1000"? ;)

Comment: I have tried single \n and single \r but both didn't work. I use write function in termios.h library.

Comment: I am trying to run a program that will turn a LED on and I am sure that it normally works because I have tried it by directly connecting to that beaglebone and had no problem.

Comment: If you tried both `\n` and `\r` and neither of them worked, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to write to a wrong device.